# How to write Kotlin function that would work with all Numbers?

Tags: kotlin

This code won't work

```
fun sum(x: Number, y: Number) = x + y
println(sum(2.2, 2))
```

Answer (score 0):

No, it won't. The plus operator is actually a function and it is not declared in the Number class, but in the concrete classes extending `Number`. You can see it in the compiler errors:

```
Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch:
@InlineOnly public inline operator fun BigDecimal.plus(other: BigDecimal): BigDecimal defined in kotlin
@InlineOnly public inline operator fun BigInteger.plus(other: BigInteger): BigInteger defined in kotlin
public operator fun <T> Array<???>.plus(elements: Array<out ???>): Array<???> defined in kotlin.collections
public operator fun <T> Array<???>.plus(elements: Collection<???>): Array<???> defined in kotlin.collections
public operator fun <T> Array<Number>.plus(element: Number): Array<Number> defined in kotlin.collections
public operator fun BooleanArray.plus(element: Boolean): BooleanArray defined in kotlin.collections
public operator fun BooleanArray.plus(elements: BooleanArray): BooleanArray defined in kotlin.collections
public operator fun BooleanArray.plus(elements: Collection<Boolean>): BooleanArray defined in kotlin.collections
public operator fun ByteArray.plus(element: Byte): ByteArray defined in kotlin.collections
public operator fun ByteArray.plus(elements: ByteArray): ByteArray defined in kotlin.collections
...
```

But this code will work:

```
// Don't try this at home !!!
fun sum(x: Number, y: Number) = x.toDouble() + y.toDouble()
```

Well, it will compile at least. For two BigDecimals you rather won't get the expected result.

Comment: Indeed.  And there's no reasonable implementation which _would_ give the expected result for all `Number` implementations.  What result would you expect from a `Long` and a `Double`, for example?  None of the usual types could hold the result without losing precision in some cases.  (I guess you could write your own BigFloat class and return that, but it would be a serious amount of work.)

Comment: You want this: https://sidburn.github.io/blog/2016/03/24/higher-kinded-polymorphism